# Change cell format type based on combo box selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Let's say that I have a combo box that contains the following:

```
Revenue
Conversions
CTR
```

Now if I were to display "Revenue" I would expect the cells to contain "$" and "Conversions" to contain numbers with comma separators and CTR to be formatted in "%" percentage.

How would one make it so that these cells would change their format based on the selection in the combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at conditional formatting:

[image]

Repeat with a 'New Rule' for each list entry.

Comment: Now for some reason there isn't an option to change the format based on the conditional. It will only allow me change the border color, cell color, font, and other options that are not changing the format.

Comment: Ahhhh!! It's because it's not available on the Mac Version! Arggh! It works on my windows machine, though. Thanks!